# Add new column in Dataframe pyspark with maximum value of another column on range of 2 dates present in another column

Tags: pyspark, databricks

| date | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1995-10-24 | 10 |
| 1995-10-25 | 20 |
| 1995-10-26 | 30 |
| 1995-10-27 | 11 |
| 1995-10-28 | 14 |
| 1995-10-29 | 12 |

I need to add new column in dataframe which will have maximum value of price between (date and date-2 days)

| date | price | new_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1995-10-24 | 10 | 10 |
| 1995-10-25 | 20 | 20 |
| 1995-10-26 | 30 | 30 |
| 1995-10-27 | 11 | 30 |
| 1995-10-28 | 14 | 30 |
| 1995-10-29 | 12 | 14 |

new column =  max(price) between (date,date-2)

Please provide pyspark code for adding new column for this scenario

new column =  max(price) between (date,date-2)

Comment: so, the thing is SO is not a code writing service. we can help you resolve errors in "your" code though. have you tried anything? see `rangeBetween` in window. [ask], [mcve]

Comment: which databricks you are using. aws,azure or community?